# matches happen but replacement not happening

Tags: perl

the line that I want to replace:

```
1.my_type   NEW{ 2}   my type
2.my_type   TEST{ 0}  my type
```

my expected output:

```
1. my_type  NEW{ 0x02}  my type
2. my_type  TEST{ 0x00} my type
```

I want to replace `NEW{2}` with `NEW{0x02}` and `NEW{0}` with `NEW{0x00}`

for all the occurrence it matches in a file

my_code:

```
        while (<DATA>)
        {
        if (/NEW\s+[{2}]\d+/) 
            {
           s/NEW{ 2}/NEW{ 0x02}/ ;
            }
        elsif (/NEW\s+[{0}]\d+/) 
            {
           s/NEW{ 0}/NEW{ 0x00}/ ;
            }
        }
```

why the replacement is not happening..?

Comment: You formatted most of your question as a quote, and the actual question as code. Why? Please learn to use markdown properly.

Comment: You forgot to escape the curly brackets

Comment: @simbabque actually by mistake I have formatted wrongly .I will format properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use multiple substitutions you can do it with one. Try this

```
s/NEW *\{ *([02])* \}/NEW{ 0x0$1}/;
```

and you don't need the conditionals. So something like that should do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/NEW *\{ *([02]) *\}/NEW{ 0x0$1}/;
    # do something with $_ here, e.g.:
    print $_;
}

__DATA__
1.my_type   NEW{ 2} my type
2.my_type   NEW{ 0} my type
```

Essentially, the substitution operator handles the conditionals for you. It will perform the substitution only if the regex matches.

Comment: I have tried to replace s/NEW *\{ *([02])* \}/NEW{ 0x0$1}/;
but its not happening. When I print its printing the entire line

Comment: Oops, my bad, I had misplaced a `*`. Can you try again?

Comment: still replacement is not happening what I want to do. Whichever places NEW is present in file it should be replaced with NEW {2}  my type --> NEW {0x02}  my type

Comment: Well, my code does exactly that. Test the complete example I included in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your input

```
1.my_type   NEW{ 2} my type
2.my_type   NEW{ 0} my type
```

does not match your test

```
if (/NEW\s+[{2}]\d+/)
elsif (/NEW\s+[{0}]\d+/)
```

because the test requires at least one space between the `W` and the `{`, and disallows the space after the `{`.